# python find the nearest nonzero element in df column

Tags: python, pandas

I have df:

```
id   number
1     5
1      0
1      0
1      2    
2      0
3      1
```

I want to write a function to fill 0 values.I want for each id(for each group) , when the value in number column is zero, to search the closet non zero value in the column and return the value. for example to id 1 to fill the second  and third-row with 2. If I dont have such value like in id 2 , just to remain it as is.
How can I do that?

Comment: mask zeroes then use either ffill or bfill with a groupby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `mask` the 0, `bfill` per group, finally fillna with then original value for the groups than only have zeros:

```
df['number2'] = (df['number']
 .mask(df['number'].eq(0))
 .groupby(df['id'])
 .bfill()
 .fillna(df['number'], downcast='infer')
)
```

output:

```
   id  number  number2
0   1       5        5
1   1       0        2
2   1       0        2
3   1       2        2
4   2       0        0
5   3       1        1
```

Comment: why do I need to use min ? I need the nonzero value that is the closet(by place,index) to the zero value

Comment: @nena if you have no negative value, the `min` is the value closest to zero, have you tried if it works for you?

Comment: I didnt mean close by value, i meant close by place. for example if I have 1,0,0,20 so i will get 1,20,20,20 because the next nonzero value is 20

Comment: But the value closest to the first 0 is 1, not 20